# Possible to set base directory for a J2EE webapp on a request-by-request basis?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, jetty

We've got a Java/J2EE web application where different users should see different pages. We have the user log in, stick the userId in the sesssion, and let them use the webapp.

What I'd like to do is have a separate directory for each user where they can see their own files and web pages. Ideally, I'd be able to create a servlet filter that would see the userId, and set the base directory for the webapp just for that request. The base directory would need to exist outside the /webapps directory.

Is there any way to do this using standard servlet stuff?

If not, is it possible to do using servlet container-specific code? We could use either Jetty or Tomcat, or possibly even Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to decide what it is you want to do:

- If you just want users to be able to log in and see files and web pages, forget about J2EE and just configure an Apache web server to do that. It can do secure logins, browse users' home directories, etc.
- If you do want to go the J2EE route, you'll have to write a servlet to read out the user's credentials, and then use the `java.io.File` API to fish out the contents of that directory. To display a web page, open an `InputStream` on the particular file you want to display, and copy it to the servlet's OutputStream. Don't forget to set the content type on the `HttpServletResponse` correctly (e.g. "text/html" for a web page).

Comment: I think that writing our own servlet is what we'll have to do. The trouble is that we'll have to duplicate everything that the default static file handler does in a servlet container. There's probably a lot of stuff in there: caching, zip compression, etc.. I've no desire to reinvent the wheel, hence the question.